# How do I extend this container from top to bottom edge of viewport?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

So, I'm working on my Wordpress theme for my personal website, and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do a couple things:

1)  I need for the white to extend above the top edge of the page content

2)  I'd like for the container to extend to the bottom edge of the viewport if possible.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for all of my layout stuff.   Source is viewable by normal means, etc.

I tried using `min-height: 100%` in various places, haven't had much luck.  Maybe it just wasn't in the right place, who knows.

Thanks ahead of time for any response!

Comment: Can you show an example on bootply or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm an idiot, I forgot to actually link my website:

http://charlesbaker.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the white to extend to the top, remove `padding-top` from the `.page-container` and add it to `page-outline` instead. Also add `height: 100%` to the `page-outline`.

So your CSS looks like this for `page-container` and `page-outline`:

```
.page-container {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.page-outline {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yay!   THanks a lot.  That fixed it right up.  Accepting solution for sure.  :)